# show all accessible sites on team site homepage

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites

How can I change the homepage of my teamsite so it displays all sites to which each user has access to. This seems so obvious (not forcing users to search and then follow sites, before they show up on the company homepage).

I browsed the net for hours and came across A LOT OF simular requests

Why is this even an issue ? so obvious :-S

Answer (score 1):

You can edit home page, add a search results web part->edit search results web part->change query->type Contentclass:sts_site, and then click OK, save the page, it will show all accessible sites on team site homepage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty easy, the hard part is to define what to show and what it should look like.
I usually add a search resultat source on tenant or farm level as I might need to use it on multiple site collections. The query should look for subsites and or site collections based on your setup.
Next step could be to setup a page containing the holy trinity: search box, search resultat and a refiner web part. You might have to tweak the managed properties in order to get the proper fields available in the refiner. Last step could be to clone the display templates and make the sites appear as cards or similar